# Problem installing Windows Phone Apps

Tags: apps, store

My problem is I had some apps that won't install giving me different error codes ... I tried to fix these problems but failed so I reset my phone

Apps are installing now but there are some of the apps that are not installing giving me this error:

We are having problems installing this app . If this is the first time you see this error then try again . If the app still wont install check your phone update and set your phone up to date.

My date and time are OK. My OS is up to date . My connection is good and my outlook account is synced.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Can you please share the error code displayed and the OS version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to storage settings and change your install location from SD card to phone.

If it still doesn't work, then it means that the app can't be run in your language.